# Compounding interest calculator with monthly contributions

Tags: javascript

I'm really struggling with what seems should be a fairly simple calculation...

I would like to calculate the compounding interest of an initial investment, with monthly contributions...

This is what I have so far:

```js
function makeInvestingCalculation() {
  let princ = 3500; // start deposit
  let add = 250; // monthly deposit (need plus it every year)
  let rate = 12 / 100; // interest rate divided to create decimal
  let months = (10 * 12); //10 years of monthly contributions
  for (let i = 0; i < months; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
      princ += add;
    }
    princ += princ * rate;
  }
  console.log(princ.toFixed(2)); //4498379090.49
}

makeInvestingCalculation();
```

This produces `4498379090.49` which is clearly incorrect.

The correct answer is supposed to be `69,636.12` but I am unable to find this...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're paying 12% interest every month. Is it supposed to be 12% per year?

Comment: You don't need a loop, there's a formula. See https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/articles/finance/compound-interest-formula.php

Comment: Ah yes, adding `if(i % 12 == 0) {` around the `princ += princ * rate;` but that still doesn't produce the correct answer

Comment: You need to pay interest every month, but not 12%. You need to convert the annual rate to a monthly rate.

Comment: I tried a number of combinations but can't get to exactly 69636.12. (Close to it, but not exact.) The parameters of the problem are unclear, please specify exactly what the interest rate is supposed to be and when it and the additional per month is added, and how it relates with the yearly rate. Can you include the entire problem statement in the question?

Comment: I get his expected result at https://financialmentor.com/calculator/compound-interest-calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is (as @CertainPerformance correctly pointed out)

```js
princ += princ * rate;
```

Since you are compounding monthly, you need to divide the annual rate by 12 (months), so

```js
princ += princ * (rate/12);
```

The second, subtler issue is

```js
for (let i = 0; i < months; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
      princ += add;
    }
```

you are skipping the first payment, which might make since intuitively since you aren't making a contribution in the 0th month, however, since the loop condition is `< months` and not `<= months` you are *also* skipping the last contribution, so your loop stops 1 contribution early. Conceptually, the loop condition makes more sense to me as this:

```js
for(let i=1; i <= 12*10; i++)
```

so then

```js
  let princ = 3500; // start deposit
  let add = 250; // monthly deposit (need plus it every year)
  let rate = 12 / 100; // interest rate divided to create decimal
  let months = (10 * 12); //10 years of monthly contributions
  for (let i = 1; i <= months; i++) {
    princ += add;
    princ += princ * (rate / 12);
    console.log(princ);
  }
  console.log(princ.toFixed(2)); //69636.12
```

Comment: This is a great response, and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @Simon glad it helped!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. The official government compound interest calculator gets $67,968.08.

https://www.investor.gov/financial-tools-calculators/calculators/compound-interest-calculator

I can't seem to pin down any formula that matches up with their calculator.

Comment: @Jaredar1232 If you use this one: http://www.moneychimp.com/calculator/compound_interest_calculator.htm It lets you pick if the contribution is made at the *start* or the *end* of the compounding period. If you choose start, you get `69,636.12`. If you choose end, you get `69,061.03` which is also what I got on the investor.gov calculator

Answer (score 1):

I read the answer of @chiliNUT, and it's perfect, I want to add a little bit to it, as you know deposits can be made start and end of the month and most calculator uses the end-of-month technique so here is the code for that.

```
 let princ = 10000; // start deposit
let add = 500; // monthly deposit (need plus it every year)
let rate = 0.06; // interest rate divided to create decimal
let months = (41 * 12); //41 years of monthly contributions
for (let i = 1; i <= months; i++) {

    princ += princ * (rate / 12);
    princ += add;
    console.log(princ);
}
console.log(princ.toFixed(2));
```